# Issue with responsive text box on hero

Tags: html, css

I have a question regarding a responsive issue I am having with a text box overlapping a hero. The text box is aligned to the left of the hero and on resize I want to keep it with the same margin, however it is just disappearing on resize.

I have attached an image of my current progress and would love if anyone could help me out on this! When it gets to a tablet size (maybe 768px) it would be great if it could align centre as well.

I apologize that you can't see the hero image on the code snippet, but I have attached an image of what it should look like:

[[image: Image of design here]]

```css
.hero-image {
  background-image: url("../images/banner-top.png");
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: black;
  border: 8px solid orange;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  padding: 30px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .info-box-wrappper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-image" src="../images/banner-top.png">
  <div class="info-box-wrappper">
    <div class="hero-text">
      <h2>For more information...</h2>
      <h1>Contact us!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have not added `.hero-text` css for reponsive in snippet

Comment: Hello @Vitorinofernandes what do you mean bud? Sorry i am just quite stuck and new with this, thanks :)